# How can you connect to my_app.meteor.com's MONGO DB locally?

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to connect to my deployed mongo URL locally. Not from the command line, but to power my local app. It doesn't seem to work. Is this possible? What's the easiest (and cheapest) way to use a remote Mongo DB and connect to it from other clients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run

```
meteor mongo yourapp.meteor.com --url
```

You should get something that matches up to

mongodb://**username**:**password**@**host**:**port**/**databasename**

You can then use [some gui app](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/) to access it using these details.

Also you **must** connect with these details within 1 minute. The username and password given with this will expire after 1 minute, then you would need to do it again to get a new username and password.

Once you connect then you will stay connected till you disconnect, though.

You could theoretically also use this to power your local mongodb app by passing the URL into the `MONGO_URL` environment variable. I guess the guys running meteor.com discourage this and it's probably why the usernames and passwords expire after a minute. (Since if there is a network interruption you would be disconnected until you provide the new credentials)

MongoHQ and MongoLab offer free 512mb MongoDb sandboxes to test your app on you might want to consider checking those out instead.

Answer (score 2):

`meteor mongo yourapp.meteor.com --url`

You get the MONGO_URL there and just copy it.

`MONGO_URL="url:you@got:with_above/command" meteor`

So basically akshat's answer is correct; if you're unable to getting into the production db with app interface, please provide little more info about the situation. In a previous project, I was connected to production app all the time and didn't have any problems with connections breaking. Not noticeable problems at least.