# How to deploy my local mongodb in meteor deploy service

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I would like to use my `local` mongodb in my deploy link in meteor.com free hosting service, is this possible?

if so how can I export the mongodb into the deploy site? `meteor whateversite.meteor.com`

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB / Meteor / Export MONGO\_URL to deployed applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971036/mongodb-meteor-export-mongo-url-to-deployed-applications)

Comment: is similar question but not exactly the same, Im only concern to export my localhost mongodb to meteor.com hosting service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use MongoChef http://3t.io/mongochef to export & import collections from local mongoDB to any live one,

To get domain.meteor.com mongoDB access details run

`meteor mongo domain.meteor.com --url`

Please review Akshat answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23982518/3136253